# How are instant messages sent to Android apps?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Imagine a user has the Facebook android app installed, but not open.

When a user receives a chat message from a friend, this appears on the phone. Is this utilizing Google Cloud Messaging push notifications to deliver chat messages? Is this the best practice approach for sending messages to users?

Or, does the android app (Facebook/whatsapp/wechat) need to open a persistent Web socket connection?

Answer (score 1):

For the applications you specifically listed:

Facebook Messenger uses [MQTT](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/building-facebook-messenger/10150259350998920). WhatsApp is widely known to use XMPP. Both of these applications use a long-lived socket connection.

With that being said though, GCM is the easiest to set up.

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean even if the android app isn't active, it will need to keep a persistent connection open? Will that use up the battery life?

Comment: @android-user To your first question, Yes. Typically you do this through a Service. For your second question, an idle TCP connection does not use any bandwidth or the CPU aside from sending a "keepalive" packet. So in an idle connection the battery life usage will be determined by the time between "keepalive" packets.

Answer (score 1):

We can use Push Notification for messaging purpose. 
The best way is to use **XMPP** protocol.
you can find the example below
[Simple messaging application using XMPP](https://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/)

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean even if the android app isn't active, it will need to keep a persistent connection open? Will that use up the battery life?

Comment: GCM maintains the XMPP connection for you, so on Android you don't have to worry about maintaining the connection or its effect on battery life. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs